# Delete duplicated rows in mysql where timestamp interval is less than 5 seconds

Tags: mysql

I have a server that adds several records to a DB on each visit. The server did it between 2-5 records for each visit. All the data between is the same expect the timestamp. I want to keep only 1 record per visit. And delete the other records.

**Before:**

```
+----+----------------------+------+--------+
| id |      timestamp       | user | action |
+----+----------------------+------+--------+
|  1 | 01-01-01-16 03:02:05 |    5 | visit  |
|  2 | 01-01-01-16 03:02:06 |    5 | visit  |
|  3 | 01-01-01-16 03:02:05 |    6 | watch  |
|  4 | 01-01-01-16 03:02:06 |    6 | watch  |
|  5 | 01-01-01-16 03:04:05 |    9 | visit  |
|  6 | 01-01-01-16 03:04:06 |    9 | visit  |
|  7 | 01-01-01-16 03:04:07 |    9 | visit  |
|  8 | 01-01-01-16 03:04:35 |    2 | see    |
+----+----------------------+------+--------+
```

**Expected Results:**

```
+----+----------------------+------+--------+
| id |      timestamp       | user | action |
+----+----------------------+------+--------+
| 1, | 01-01-01-16 03:02:05 |    5 | visit  |
| 3, | 01-01-01-16 03:02:05 |    6 | watch  |
| 4, | 01-01-01-16 03:02:06 |    6 | watch  |
| 5, | 01-01-01-16 03:04:05 |    9 | visit  |
| 8, | 01-01-01-16 03:04:35 |    2 | see    |
+----+----------------------+------+--------+
```

**In other words:** As you see, line 1,2 are identical.  same user, and only one seconds between. So I delete line 2. Line 4 I'm not touching because it is not a  visit

I have the begining of the query: `delete from table where id in(...)`

Comment: check http://sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to create better tables

Comment: so how much time between visit is consider the same record?

Comment: at maximum 5 seconds

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the link you send me goes to nowhere. This is the link: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: select the table and press `ctrl-k` to indent 4 space and appear as code

Comment: Check the tables now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` to execute your query faster

```
DELETE t1 FROM visit t1
INNER JOIN visit t2 ON v1.user = v2.user
WHERE v1.id < v2.id AND
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp) < 5 AND 
t1.action = 'visit' AND
t2.action = 'visit'
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the syntax is valid in mysql? `delete t1 from...`? what is it mean to delete in join?

Comment: yes, when you create `join` in `delete` query, you suppose to define from which table you want to delete the data.

Comment: Thanks you. Really help.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM visit 
       WHERE id IN (
               SELECT v2.id 
               FROM visit v1           
               JOIN visit v2
                 ON v1.id < v2.id
                AND v1.user = v2.user                    
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, v1.timestamp, v2.timestamp) < 5  
               WHERE v1.action = 'visit'         
                 AND v2.action = 'visit'                              
               )
```

Comment: Why you add `where v1.action='visit'` to  the `where` section and not to the `on` section ?

Comment: I usually put the `field = constant` on the where ... on the `ON`  i put `field1 =  field2`